# What could cause PHP application running on Apache, with MySQL database to freeze until clearing cookies?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, session

There is an old PHP (version 4 or 5, I'm not really sure) [application](https://sourceforge.net/projects/assetssosimple/) running on an old CentOS (don't know the version) with Apache2. It used to be connected to an MySQL 4 database with MyISAM storage engine. The database was hosted on the same server as the application, if that matters. The PHP application uses the database for session management: it will write a session id in one of the tables (Employees) and will remove it when a logout is performed.

There was a recent update on the MySQL side: the database was moved to a newer (version 5.7.29) remote server, running Ubuntu 18. The database was also converted to InnoDB. SQL mode was set to "" (empty), as it previously was on the older database.

This was necessary in order to connect another application to the same database as the initial PHP app. The other application is written in Django 3 and is running on a separate server (also Ubuntu 18, with Apache 2.2). There is no issue with the Django application, everything is running smooth. I don't know if it matters, but it also uses the table with the PHP session id.

The issue is as it follows: multiple users will connect to the PHP application and do some stuff (insert assets, view assets, insert employees etc.). I don't know why, but for some of these users, the application will suddenly freeze. Some users can access the web page, while others can not. Sometimes it will freeze when trying to login, other times when trying to logout and sometimes in the middle of doing stuff. If the same user will try to connect the PHP app from another browser, the application will work fine, still not responding on the initial browser. If it clears the cookies on the frozen browser and refreshes, the application will work fine.

The issue is that I don't have access to the server running the PHP application. I only have access to the database and the Django app. Using the developer tools of the browser, I can see that the PHP application will set 2 cookies: PHPSESSID (expires/max age: session) and sessionid (expires/max age: sometime in 2021 and secure), both having the same value as the session id written in the database table.

The issue is clearly related to the session, because it will disappear once the cookies are cleared or the browser is changed. What could be the root of the issue, though?

Comment: I'm afraid one can not give a proper answer to that question without doing root cause analysis. Do you have any chance to take a look at the server/error logs? Or maybe binding some monitoring tool like new relic for example?

Comment: User Dimitriy Solokhin asked me to write his comment as he doesn't have enough reputation to post comments: _I've had the same issue. My website was hosted with godaddy. They did something like reinstall/refresh php version and the problem was gone ever since. I still don't know what they did on their end, but maybe reach out to the host and see if they can help._

Comment: Probably session locking. Only one PHP process can have the session open at one time, and there's probably a request that doesn't complete properly, or you've done something inadvisable like backgrounding a PHP process to accomplish long-running task.

Comment: That said, every version of everything you mentioned is so far out of date it's giving me anxiety. You should strongly consider migrating to current _everything_ and incinerating that security deathtrap ASAP.

Comment: @sammitch unfortunately I have no control over the PHP application. I only manage the Django one.